# Detecting multiple GZip members without downloading the whole blob

Tags: c#, .net, azure, gzip, azure-blob-storage

1. I have a service which transforms and transfers blobs from one storage to another.
2. The blobs can be either `gzip`'ed or raw data.
3. I do not allow multiple *members* in a single `gzip`'ed blob - due to limitations in the `.NET` framework's `gzip` class.
4. My goal is to reject `gzip`'ed blobs that consist of two or more *memebers* in `O(1)`.
5. By `O(1)`, I mean by not reading the whole blob or big parts of it.

I've read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) and I've got a feeling that given:

1. The blob's size
2. The `ISIZE` footer of the last *member*

We can work something out to ensure with very very low probability for false-positive (i.e. rejecting a single-*memeber* blob) and false-negative (i.e. allowing multiple-*members* blobs) that a blob is either single-member or multiple-member gzip.

Have anyone had dealt with this issue successfully?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can get zip file count using memory stream without download the zip file to local directory.  The following is my test sample demo, it works correctly for me. More detail about how to operate Azure blob with SDK please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs).Add `System.IO.Compression.dll` from system dlls.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("You connection string");

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("testcont"); //your container name

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.zip"); //blob name

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
      blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
      using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream))
      {
          var count = zip.Entries.Count;
      }
      // Todo list   we can use CloudBlockBlob.StartCopy to copy blob to another storage  
}
```

[image]
  More info about CloudBlockBlob.StartCopy please refer to [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt433229.aspx).

SDK info please refer to the packages.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: This solution still downloads the whole blob. I'm trying to avoid this - regardless of the download's destination (local directory or memory).

If there is kind of solution for the above problem - then I'm more interested in the low level explanation of how it's possible given the RFC.

Comment: If the gizp files are not uploaded to the azure blobs, we could add [metedata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-properties-metadata) for these blobs during uploading.